# How can I format a date in javascript without using moment.js

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to convert my date object to mm/dd/yy hh/mm

```
   newDateObj = new Date(dateString).toLocaleString();
```

Output is 12/7/1913, 1:31:52 PM but i dont want the seconds.

Comment: use library like moment.js

Comment: is there another way just to trim seconds

Comment: What is `dateString`? is it just `new Date()`

Comment: yes say its like in the json structure                                                                              
      {
       dateString "1913-12-07T17:41:52+0000"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working without momentum

```
   var options = {month: '2-
   digit', day: '2-digit', year: '2-digit',hour: '2-digit', minute:'2-digit'};

   newDateObj= new Date(dateString).toLocaleString([], options );
```

Output is 12/7/1913, 1:31:52 PM

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MomentJS](https://momentjs.com/) and combine `moment("1913-12-07T17:41:52").format('L'); // 12/07/1913` with `moment("1913-12-07T17:41:52").format('LT');  // 5:41 AM`